# No URI handler implemented for \"gst-pipeline\"." - using PyQt 5.15

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, gstreamer

I am writing a simple video player with gstreamer and PyQt 5.15.8.

The code is a slightly modified version from [this website](https://coderslegacy.com/python/pyqt5-video-player-with-qmediaplayer/) where I replaced:

```py
    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Movie",
                QDir.homePath())

        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                    QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
```

by

```py
    def openFile(self):
        pipeline = f"gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! autovideosink"
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
            QMediaContent(QUrl(pipeline)))
```

as a test of the gst-pipeline feature as I would like to be able to pass my own pipeline for network streaming.

Here is the full code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication,
                             QLabel, QFileDialog, QStyle, QVBoxLayout)
import sys

class VideoPlayer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Video Player") 

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.openButton = QPushButton("Open Video")   
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.openButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.playButton)

        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)

    def openFile(self):
        pipeline = f"gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! autovideosink"
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
            QMediaContent(QUrl(pipeline)))

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
videoplayer = VideoPlayer()
videoplayer.resize(640, 480)
videoplayer.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: " videotestsrc ! autovideosink" : "no element \"autovideosink\""
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! autovideosink"
Error: "No URI handler implemented for \"gst-pipeline\"."
```

All the answers I found regarding the same error point at a version of PyQt5 that is too old, but the gst-pipeline feature is supported since Qt 5.12.2 as from the doc and I am using 5.15 so it should work in theory. What am I missing?

*Edit: I am using mac OS Ventura 13.3.1 with M1 architecture*

*Edit 2: When running with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` I get the following output:*

```
Qt: v 5.15.8    PyQt: v 5.15.9
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "cocoa"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QCocoaIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("cocoa")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platformthemes" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platformthemes/libqxdgdesktopportal.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platformthemes/libqxdgdesktopportal.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformThemeFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xdgdesktopportal",
            "flatpak",
            "snap"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXdgDesktopPortalThemePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xdgdesktopportal", "flatpak", "snap")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/platformthemes" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/styles" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/styles/libqmacstyle.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/styles/libqmacstyle.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QStyleFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "macintosh"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMacStylePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("macintosh")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/styles" ...
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/styles/libqmacstyle.dylib"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstaudiodecoder.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstaudiodecoder.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gstreameraudiodecode"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.audiodecode"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGstreamerAudioDecoderServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreameraudiodecode")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstcamerabin.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstcamerabin.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gstreamercamerabin"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.camera"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "CameraBinServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreamercamerabin")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediacapture.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediacapture.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gstreamermediacapture"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.audiosource"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGstreamerCaptureServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreamermediacapture")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gstreamermediaplayer"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGstreamerPlayerServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreamermediaplayer")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "avfoundationcamera"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.camera"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "AVFServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("avfoundationcamera")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "avfoundationmediaplayer"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "AVFMediaPlayerServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("avfoundationmediaplayer")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libqtmedia_audioengine.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libqtmedia_audioengine.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "audiocapture"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.audiosource"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "AudioCaptureServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("audiocapture")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/mediaservice" ...
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer.dylib"
QMediaPluginLoader: loaded plugins for key "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer" : ("gstreamermediaplayer", "avfoundationmediaplayer")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/resourcepolicy" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/resourcepolicy" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/iconengines" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QIconEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "svg",
            "svgz",
            "svg.gz"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QSvgIconPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("svg", "svgz", "svg.gz")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/iconengines" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gif"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/gif"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGifPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gif")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "icns"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/x-icns"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QICNSPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("icns")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "ico",
            "cur"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/vnd.microsoft.icon",
            "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QICOPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("ico", "cur")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "jpg",
            "jpeg"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/jpeg"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QJpegPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("jpg", "jpeg")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqmacheif.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqmacheif.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "heic",
            "heif"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/heic",
            "image/heif"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMacHeifPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("heic", "heif")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqmacjp2.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqmacjp2.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "jp2"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/jp2",
            "image/jpx",
            "image/jpm",
            "video/mj2"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMacJp2Plugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("jp2")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "svg",
            "svgz"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/svg+xml",
            "image/svg+xml-compressed"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QSvgPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("svg", "svgz")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "tga"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/x-tga"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QTgaPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("tga")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "tiff",
            "tif"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/tiff",
            "image/tiff"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QTiffPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("tiff", "tif")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wbmp"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWbmpPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wbmp")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webp"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/webp"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebpPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webp")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/imageformats" ...
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqmacheif.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqmacjp2.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.dylib"
loaded library "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.dylib"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/video/gstvideorenderer" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/video/gstvideorenderer" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/accessible" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/bin/accessible" ...
2023-09-20 11:03:58.284 python[51572:1372646] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2023-09-20 11:03:58.395 python[51572:1372646] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
Error: " videotestsrc ! autovideosink" : "no element \"autovideosink\""
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! autovideosink"
Error: "No URI handler implemented for \"gst-pipeline\"."
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqmacheif.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqmacjp2.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/styles/libqmacstyle.dylib" 
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/switch/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib"
```

Comment: Works fine for me on arch-linux using Qt-5.15.10. Do you have all the necessary gst plugins installed? I have good/bad/ugly, plus libav (ffmpeg) - but I don't know which specific ones are relevant. Have you tried running `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink` in a terminal? You could also try e.g. `ximagesink` or `glimagesink`. (NB: The command in the question displays the video in a separate window, but it can be rendered in the player itself with `gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! xvimagesink name=qtvideosink`).

Comment: I forgot to mention my system spec, I am using mac OS with M1 architecture (I've added the macos tag now).
I have no problem running `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink`.
I am only trying passing pipelines that I verified where running in the terminal.

Comment: I think Qt only includes gstreamer by default on linux. So unless your Qt build explicitly compiled in gstreamer support, you won't be able acsess it (which seems to be confirmed by the error message). Try running `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python path/to/script.py`. The output should include plugin meta data for "gstreamermediaplayer", "gstreameraudiodecode", etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the output to the original post and I can see meta data related to gstreamer.

Comment: Maybe there's a plugin path issue whereby Qt can't find the *libgstautodetect* plugin that includes autovideosink. Do you get a similar error when using `gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! glimagesink`? If so, try setting `GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH_1_0` or `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` to the path that contains the *libgstautodetect* plugin. You might also try setting `GST_DEBUG=*:6`. That should produce lots of output, but it might offer some clues (see [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/running.html#running-and-debugging-gstreamer-applications) for more details).